# How to make use of the binaries preview that's published by Google?

Tags: android, adb, bootloader

How to make use of the binaries preview that's published by Google?
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/blobs-preview

I `repo sync`-ed the android source and downloaded the Android binary preview for nexus 4 from the Android developer website. I extracted the binary and moved the `vendor/` folder to the root of the android source tree and did `make` with `AOSP_MAKO_USERDEBUG` configuration. Once `make` is done, I did `flash all`. Is this the correct way of using the binary review? Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this question isn't that it is off-topic - it concerns installing a development build on a development device, which is entirely an appropriate topic here, rather the problem is that it's woefully incomplete in the details of the problem.  There's really nothing to base an answer on other than speculation.

Comment: I apologized for the incomplete information. Let me rephrase my question in a bit.

Comment: IMHO your first version contained more relevant information.

Comment: hmm...Actually I think my question is really... what is the binary preview that is posted on the Google Site and how can I use them?